# How to make Firefox not use Flash

Tags: flash

I have set Flash to "ask to activate". Now Youtube does not load the video. How can I make Youtube use the HTML5 player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply go to http://www.youtube.com/html5 and scroll down a bit to find "Request the HTML5 Player" button.

[image: YouTube HTML5 Player Switch]

This should make YouTube use the HTML5 player instead of the Flash Player.

Answer (score 1):

Start by installing a media player plug-in for Firefox. Personally I prefer the tighter VLC:

`sudo apt-get install browser-plugin-vlc`

Restart Firefox and then access this web page:

https://www.youtube.com/html5

There activate the checkbox "The HTML5 player is currently used when possible."

Comment: The plugin is not needed if you're going to use HTML5.. HTML5 Video is the function of the browser, not a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can go here:
https://www.youtube.com/html5?gl=EN

and set the HTML5 player instead of the default flash player